# Is there any way to make the java google appengine web application a OAuth2.0 Service provider?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0

I would like to make my gae application a Service provider using OAuth2.0. Are there any client libraries which makes an gae application a Service provider. I'm using Scribe client library to be a OAuth consumer.